# Can squid http proxy dump all client/server headers?

Tags: squid

Can squid dump the client and server HTTP headers? There are some complicated web flows from machines we don't control, but which passes through our proxy, that we'd like to debug.

Answer (score 3):

Google suggests that you want the [`log_mime_hdrs`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/log_mime_hdrs/) directive.